# How to import a js file module in ASP.NET CORE MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc

I just created a js module file on wwwroot/js/base.js:

```
export const elements = {
...somthing
};
```

When I try to import it from wwwroot/js/site.js, such as

```
import {elements} from './base';
```

I geth this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to import a js file module,you need to add like this(You must use `type="module"` in script tag):

```
<script type="module" src="~/js/site.js"></script>
```

site.js is imported in `Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` by default.You can check  `Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` and change

```
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="module" src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to update the JS version of the file after you added the type="module" as below:

```
<script type="module" src="~/js/site.js?v=101" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

Because your browser can cache already existing scripts.